# what is the structure of the group of isogenies between two ordinary elliptic curve?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two ordinary elliptic curves. It is well known that the group $Home(E_1,E_2)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$ module of rank at most four. In the case where $E_1=E_2$, this module has rank two. Could we say anything about the rank of this module in general cases?

Comment: What do you call the general case? If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are general, there is no isogeny betwwen them.

Comment: I mean if they are isogenous what can we say about the number of generators of $Hom(E_1,E_2)$. Is it can be greater than two?

Comment: If they are isogeny, since you want the number of generators, is the same as taking $E_1 = E_2$ (just compose with the dual isogeny), so no. The rank is either 0 or 2 in the ordinary case